# PHP unexpected end of file parse error

Tags: php, mysql

Basically i'm creating a event based booking system with php and in HTML, the code is in bold

```
<?php    // editappt.php    // Edit appointment calendar items    //
    List globals for reference    global $link, $result, $time, $date,
    $idx, $submit_err, $cmd, $begtime, $endtime, $subj, $notes, $idx;   
    // Return the variables from GET    function get_vars()    {
            global  $date, $time, $submit_err;
            foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
            {
                 $key = $value;
            }    }   /* Return the variables from POST -- doing this AFTER processing GET variables ensures that POST variables are not altered
    by the URL */   function post_vars()   {
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
          global $key;
          $key = $value;
          print $value;
        }   }   // Open connection to DB   function open_db()   {
        $db = "calendar";
        $link = mysql_connect(localhost,root,"") or die("Could not connect to server! Error: ".mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($db,$link) or die("Could not select $db! Error: ".mysql_error());
        return($link);   }   // Get the appt for the specified date and time   function get_appt($date,$time)   {
        global $link;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM appts WHERE date = '$date ' ";
        $query = $query."AND (\"$time\" >= begtime AND \"$time\" <= endtime)";
        $result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die("Query Error!<p>Query: $query<p> Error: " + mysql_error());
        // Return the results
        return($result);   }   // Print the appt form for $date   function print_appt($result)   {      print $link + $date + $time +
    $submit_err + $begtime + $endtime + $subj + $notes + $idx;   }
        // Assemble select list "name" from first to last by step
        //   match = initially selected item, time = format for time    function print_list($name,$first,$last,$step,$match,$time)    {
            print "<select name=\"$name\" size=\"1\">";
            if ($tmp == $match)
            {
                echo " selected";
                echo ">$tmp\n";
            }
                    else
                    {
                        $tmp = $x;
                    }
             for ($x = $first; $x <= $last; $x=$x+$step)
                    {
                        echo "\t<option";
                        if ($time)
                        {
                            $tmp = date("H:i",$x);
                        }
                         echo "</select>\n";
            $this_script = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        // If this isnt a redisplay because of error, init vars
        if (!$submit_err)
        {
            $begtime = $time;
            $endtime = $time;
            $subj = "";
            $notes = "";
            $idx = 0;
            $cmd = "write";
          // Get fields for appt, if one exists
          // (else use values above)
         }
        while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
          {
              $begtime = substr($line[begtime],0,5);
              $endtime = substr($line[endtime],0,5);
              $subj = $line[subj];
              $notes = $line[notes];
              $idx = $line[idx];
              $cmd = "update";
          }    }  // Start form with state fields (hidden)  print <<<HTML  <html>  <body>  <form action="$this_script" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="$date">  <input
    type="hidden" name="cmd" value="$cmd">  <input type="hidden"
    name="idx" value="$idx">  <table border="0" width="100%">  HTML;   
    echo "<tr>\n\t<td colspan=\"2\">\n";    // Display date in M D and Y
    select lists    print_list("month",1,12,1,substr($date,5,2),FALSE); 
    print_list("day",1,31,1,substr($date,8,2),FALSE);    $year =
    substr($date,0,4);   
    print_list("year",$year-1,$year+2,1,$year,FALSE);    echo "<p>\n";  
    // Display beginning and ending time in two    //  select lists   
    $sttm = strtotime("00:00");    print_list("begtime",$sttm,($sttm +
    (1800*47)),1800
                  ,$begtime,TRUE);    echo "&nbsp;to&nbsp;";    print_list("endtime",$sttm,($sttm + (1800*47)),1800
                  ,$endtime,TRUE);    echo "\n</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n\t<td colspan=\"2\">&nbsp;";    // Print any error from last submission   
    if ($submit_err) {
         echo "<font color=\"red\">ERROR: ";
         echo "$submit_err</font>\n";    }    print "\t</td>\n</tr>\n";  // Display Subject and Notes  print <<<HTML  </select><p>  <tr>   
    <td width="10%">Subject:</td>    <td><input type="text" name="subj"
    value="$subj"
            size="40" maxlength="40"></td>  </tr>  <tr>    <td>Notes:</td>    <td>    <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="notes"
         wrap="virtual">$notes</textarea>    </td>  </tr>  </table>  <p>  <input type="submit" name="OK" value="OK">  &nbsp;&nbsp;  <input
    type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="self.close()">  </form> 
    </body>  </html>  HTML;  // Decode submission and write to DB  //  
    $cmd = whether to overwrite (rewrite) or insert (write)  function
    write_appt($idx,$date,$begtime,$endtime,$subj,$notes,$cmd)  { 
        global $link;    // Check to make sure beginning time doesnt run
    into another appt    $query = "SELECT idx,begtime,endtime,subj FROM
    appts WHERE date = \"$date\" AND ". "\"".$begtime."\" >= begtime AND
    \"".$begtime."\" <= endtime";    $result = mysql_query($query,$link)
    or die("Query Error!<p>Query: $query<p>Error: " mysql_error());   
    // If overlap (conflict) found, display error    while ($line =
    mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))    {
         if ($line[idx] != $idx)
         {
           $errtext = "Conflict: ".substr($line[begtime],0,5)."-" + substr($line[endtime],0,5).":".$line[subj];
           return($errtext);
         }    }    // Check to make sure ending time doesnt run into another appt    $query = "SELECT idx,begtime,endtime,subj FROM appts
             WHERE date = \"$date\" AND ".
                "\"".$endtime."\" >= begtime AND \"".$endtime."\" <=
         endtime";    $result = mysql_query($query,$link)
         or die("Query Error!<p>Query: $query<p>Error:
               ".mysql_error());    // If overlap (conflict) found, display error    while ($line =
    mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
         if ($line[idx] != $idx) {
           $errtext = "Conflict: ".substr($line[begtime],0,5)."-".
                       substr($line[endtime],0,5)." : ".$line[subj];
           return($errtext);
         }    }    // Build appropriate query    if ($cmd == "update") {
         $query = "UPDATE appts SET
         date='$date',begtime='$begtime',endtime='$endtime',".
                    "subj='$subj',notes='$notes' WHERE idx = '$idx'";    } else {
         $query = "INSERT INTO appts VALUES
         ('0','$date','$begtime','$endtime','$subj','$notes','0')";    }    // Handle query    $result = mysql_query($query,$link)
         or die("Query Error!<p>Query: $query<p>
               Error:  ".mysql_error());  // Close page if no errors  print <<<HTML  <html>  <body>  <form>  Appointment Saved.<p>  <input
    type="button" value="Close" onclick="self.close()">  </form> 
    </body>  </html>  HTML;  }  // Main program body  $link = open_db();
    // Called with POST arguments?  //  (From another iteration of this
    script)  if (!empty($_POST))    {       $submit_err = "";   // Get POST
    data
            post_vars();    // Properly format date (leading zeros on M & D)    if (strlen($month) == 1) { $month = "0".$month; }    if
    (strlen($day) == 1)   { $day = "0".$day; }    $date =
    $year."-".$month."-".$day;    // Proper date?    if
    (!checkdate($month,$day,$year))    {
         $submit_err = "Invalid Date!";
         print_appt($result);    }    // Valid start and end times? (start < end)?    if (strtotime($begtime) > strtotime($endtime))   
    {
         $submit_err = "Invalid Start Time!";
         print_appt($result);    }    // Subject exists?    if (strlen($subj) == 0)    {
         $submit_err = "Subject is Blank!";
         print_appt($result);    }    // Attempt write and err on conflicting appt    if (!$submit_error)    {
         $conflict = write_appt($idx,$date,$begtime, $endtime,$subj,$notes,$cmd);
         if ($conflict)
         {
             $submit_err = $conflict;
             print_appt($result);
         }    } / else  {    // Called with GET arguments?    //  (From calendar)    // Get GET data and print edit form    get_vars();   
    $result = get_appt($date,$time);    print_appt($result);  }  //
    Close DB  mysql_close($link);  ?>}
```

I keep getting an syntax error on line 320 saying unexpected end of file, can anyone tell me how and where to fix the error.`enter code here`

Comment: Could you please format your code?

Comment: You must format your post if you want some help.

Comment: I'm so glad I don't have to do nothing with such codes...

Comment: The line `WHERE date = \"$date\" AND ".` should probably start with a `"`

Comment: Please make yourself comfortable with the editing tools and improve your question, the code in it's current form makes no sense at all (it's not valid PHP code).

Answer (score 2):

Despite the code is formatted horribly, a quick glance tells me it ends with `?>}`, when it should be `}?>`.

Answer (score 0):

change at end of file

```
?>}
```

to

```
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is somewhere in this block

```
 if ($line[idx] != $idx)
         {
           $errtext = "Conflict: ".substr($line[begtime],0,5)."-" + substr($line[endtime],0,5).":".$line[subj];
           return($errtext);
         }    }    // Check to make sure ending time doesnt run into another appt    $query = "SELECT idx,begtime,endtime,subj FROM appts
             WHERE date = \"$date\" AND ".
                "\"".$endtime."\" >= begtime AND \"".$endtime."\" <=
         endtime";    $result = mysql_query($query,$link)
         or die("Query Error!<p>Query: $query<p>Error:
               ".mysql_error());    // If overlap (conflict) found, display error    while ($line =
    mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
         if ($line[idx] != $idx) {
```

You've got too many " in there which is breaking the code stream this is noticable when code highlighting is enabled on the site as it starts colouring the php in plain red which is normally used for strings.

I suggest you start counting up your " and check any inlines are properly escaped with \ etc.

More specifically its this bit

```
WHERE date = \"$date\" AND ".
                "\"".$endtime."\"
```

Answer (score 0):

And here `or die("Query Error!<p>Query: $query<p>Error: " mysql_error());`  is an error too.